# How to filter an array in Angular 11 with data?

Tags: angular, typescript, filtering, ngfor

I have a subpage with detailed data. There are thousands of records there, which I would like to filter via "id" from my route (also included in data). How to do this? I tried many things, starting from ngIf through the .filter, but all with errors, in this case, it is

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.

**component.ts**

```
export class ZawPgee2020Component implements OnInit {
    zawpl: Array<any>;
    zawplfiltered: Array<any>;
    rider: Rider;
    detailrider: DetailRider;

    constructor(private _speedwayService: SpeedwayService, private orderPipe: OrderPipe, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this._speedwayService.getZawpl()
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.zawpl = orderPipe.transform(response, "ZAWODNIK");
                });
    }

    getFilterData() {
    const zawplfiltered = this.zawpl.filter(zawpl => {
        return zawpl == this.rider.id;
        });
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
getRider(id) : Observable<any> {
    return this._http
        .get<any>("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020")
        .pipe(
            map(result => result.data.filter(p=> p.id == id)[0])
      );
}

getZawpl() {
    return this._http
        .get("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/zawpl")
        .pipe(
            map(res => res ['data']))
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<tr *ngFor="let detailrider of zawplfiltered | orderBy: order:reverse; let i = index">
    <td>{{ detailrider.ZAWODNIK }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching data from an API, there will be a delay in getting the data from the server to fill the `zawpl` variable. Modify your `getFilterData()` and use the tenary `?` operator to protect `zawpl` array variable to be undefined:

#### Try This

In the `component.ts` file

```
getFilterData() {
const zawplfiltered = this.zawpl?.filter(zawpl_ => {
    return zawpl_ == this.rider?.id;
 });
}
```

**Good luck Let me know if this works for you!!**

Comment: Thank you for picking this up. The good news is that the error disappeared, but the bad news is I still don't have any data in my table.

Comment: Probably the issue is on the service.ts I don't understand how you are implementing your code, try to use console.log() to see where are you lacking. If you find this helpful let me know.

Comment: From the console.log() I know that the `this.rider?.id"` has a correct value. I also know that unfiltered "zawpl" is fetched from the API as `let detailrider of zawpl" `is giving me all records. The problem is hidden in the zawplfiltered structure then, but I have no clue where. The `console log(this.zawpl_)` is giving me `undefined`.

Comment: Try to display zawpl array using `console log(this.zawpl)` inside the `ngOnInit()` if you are not getting anything then which means the problem is comming from the logic of fetching data from a service

Comment: I'm getting `undefined`. However, I did the same exercise in my main page, where also the Array has `undefined` in the console log, but the data is successfully loaded.

Comment: I made some progress and I'm able to see the Array & rider.id in the console.log(). However, the Array contains all data but there are no ids, only: `""` is there. What can be a reason for that?